# Netlify Function, Cannot find module, build fails

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I'm attempting to deploy a function to Netlify. I have tested it locally with

```
netlify dev
```

and things work as expected. When creating the function, I used

```
netlify functions:create --name submit-contact
```

and selected the

```
Send email with no STMP server via 'sendmail' pkg
```

boilerplate. Locally, everything works as I would like. I noticed that it creates a nested `package.json` file in my `.netlify/functions/submit-contact` directory. My directory structure is

```
./.netlify/functions/submit-contact
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── submit-contact.js
└── validations.js
```

My nested (non-root) `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemailer": "^6.2.1"
  }
}
```

When deploying, however, the build either fails or the function fails with

```
Could not find "nodemailer" module in file
```

`nodemailer` is the only dependency I have. I found a [forum post](https://community.netlify.com/t/structuring-and-deploying-a-repository-with-netlify-functions-and-multiple-dependencies/756/6) that seems to describe my issue.

I've modified my `build` command to something that I think should work, but it doesn't seem to be installing my dep and continues to fail. Here is my build command

```
"build": "cd .netlify/functions/submit-contact && npm install && cd ../../../ && gatsby build"
```

Here is my deploy log:

```
8:39:13 PM: Build ready to start
8:39:15 PM: build-image version: 9e0f207a27642d0115b1ca97cd5e8cebbe492f63
8:39:15 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.2
8:39:15 PM: buildbot version: 75cd99f62ada9e21edea53208e8baf0eab85a045
8:39:15 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
8:39:15 PM: Starting to download cache of 158.7MB
8:39:16 PM: Finished downloading cache in 593.921286ms
8:39:16 PM: Starting to extract cache
8:39:22 PM: Finished extracting cache in 6.577648977s
8:39:22 PM: Finished fetching cache in 7.237900968s
8:39:22 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
8:39:23 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
8:39:24 PM: Found netlify.toml. Overriding site configuration
8:39:24 PM: Different functions path detected, going to use the one specified in the toml file: '.netlify/functions' versus '' in the site
8:39:24 PM: Creating functions prep folder
8:39:24 PM: Starting build script
8:39:24 PM: Installing dependencies
8:39:26 PM: Started restoring cached node version
8:39:28 PM: Finished restoring cached node version
8:39:28 PM: v10.16.0 is already installed.
8:39:29 PM: Now using node v10.16.0 (npm v6.9.0)
8:39:30 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
8:39:31 PM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
8:39:32 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
8:39:32 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
8:39:32 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
8:39:32 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.9.0
8:39:47 PM: npm
8:39:47 PM:  WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
8:39:47 PM: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.8 (node_modules/fsevents):
8:39:47 PM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
8:39:47 PM: removed 1 package and audited 36486 packages in 13.66s
8:39:47 PM: found 0 vulnerabilities
8:39:47 PM: NPM modules installed
8:39:47 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
8:39:47 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
8:39:47 PM: unset GOOS;
8:39:47 PM: unset GOARCH;
8:39:47 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64';
8:39:47 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
8:39:47 PM: go version >&2;
8:39:47 PM: export GIMME_ENV='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.12.linux.amd64.env';
8:39:47 PM: go version go1.12 linux/amd64
8:39:47 PM: Installing missing commands
8:39:47 PM: Verify run directory
8:39:47 PM: Executing user command: gatsby build
8:39:50 PM: success open and validate gatsby-configs — 0.006 s
8:39:51 PM: success load plugins — 1.536 s
8:39:51 PM: success onPreInit — 0.006 s
8:39:51 PM: success delete html and css files from previous builds — 0.005 s
8:39:51 PM: success initialize cache — 0.007 s
8:39:51 PM: success copy gatsby files — 0.021 s
8:39:52 PM: success onPreBootstrap — 0.292 s
8:39:54 PM: success loading DatoCMS content — 2.508 s
8:39:54 PM: success source and transform nodes — 2.645 s
8:39:56 PM: success building schema — 1.315 s
8:39:56 PM: success createPages — 0.191 s
8:39:56 PM: success createPagesStatefully — 0.025 s
8:39:56 PM: success onPreExtractQueries — 0.004 s
8:39:56 PM: success update schema — 0.057 s
8:39:56 PM: success extract queries from components — 0.302 s
8:39:57 PM: success run static queries — 1.197 s — 7/7 5.86 queries/second
8:39:59 PM: success run page queries — 2.056 s — 44/44 21.41 queries/second
8:39:59 PM: success write out page data — 0.005 s
8:39:59 PM: success write out redirect data — 0.001 s
8:40:00 PM: success Build manifest and related icons — 0.926 s
8:40:00 PM: success onPostBootstrap — 0.928 s
8:40:00 PM: info bootstrap finished - 13.239 s
8:40:13 PM: success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles — 12.787 s
8:40:17 PM: success Building static HTML for pages — 4.170 s — 44/44 41.85 pages/second
8:40:17 PM: Generated public/sw.js, which will precache 14 files, totaling 362103 bytes.
8:40:17 PM: info Done building in 30.3 sec
8:40:18 PM: Function Dir: /opt/build/repo/.netlify/functions
8:40:18 PM: TempDir: /tmp/zisi-475981292
8:40:19 PM: Prepping functions with zip-it-and-ship-it 0.3.1
8:40:20 PM: Error: Could not find "nodemailer" module in file: /submit-contact/submit-contact.js.
8:40:20 PM: Please ensure "nodemailer" is installed in the project.
8:40:20 PM: Error prepping functions
8:40:20 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
8:40:20 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
8:40:20 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
8:40:20 PM: Finished processing build request in 1m4.869352847s
8:40:20 PM: Shutting down logging, 0 messages pending
```

Comment: For some reason a moderator deleted my answer. The issue ended up being that I needed to configure Netlify's build command to be `npm run build` instead of `gatsby build`. A [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/forms-auth-and-serverless-functions-on-gatsby-and-netlify/#article-header-id-10) article helped along with the mentioned forum post. I think using a `prebuild` command would be more ideal, but I was desperate to get the function working and once I did was happy enough.